# CakePHP 3 showing DebugKit panel

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am developing a CakePHP 3 application. In localhost, the DebugKit panel is not showing, but when I upload it to the server, the DebugKit panel is showing.

How can enable DebugKit panel on my localhost?

Note: I am loading the DebugKit Plugin in bootstrap.php. My local machine is running Windows 8.

Answer (score 4):

First, I would check your error logs to see if DebugKit itself is generating any errors, but I'm about 92.6% sure that you don't have the SQLite PHP extension installed and initialized on your local web server, which will cause DebugKit to fail gracefully upon initialization.

Let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: It's almost always my problem. =D
The package name for ubuntu/debian/mint systems is php5-sqlite

Comment: It seriously eluded me at my day job for like four months after moving to a new Linux box and finally after digging through the code I figured it out.  It was a miserable four months!  :D